# Understanding assigning to empty array

Tags: perl

From perldoc, in [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context), there is a line of code like:

```
$count = () = $string =~ /\d+/g;
```

It says $count will be set to the number of matches because assigning to the bracket means assigning to the empty list and it converts to list context. But when I do:

```
print (() = $string =~ /\d+/g);
```

I was expecting to print an array of matches but it prints nothing. If the empty list is nothing, how does the previous assignment from () to $count works? What does the first one mean by assigning to empty list and what does it actually do?

---

More specifically,

```
print $string =~ /\d+/g;                     #print all matches
print (() = $string =~ /\d+/g);              #print nothing (why)
print ($count = () = $string =~ /\d+/g);     #print number of matches (why again)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key difference ([perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#List-value-constructors)):

> List assignment in scalar context returns the number of elements
>   produced by the expression on **the right side of the assignment**:
>
> ```
> $x = (($foo,$bar) = (3,2,1)); # set $x to 3, not 2
> ```

With `$count = () = $string =~ /\d+/g;`, you impose the scalar context on the list assignment, therefore the number of matches - elements produced by `$string =~ /\d+/g` - will be stored in `$count` variable.

But with `print(() = $string =~ /\d+/g);`, it's different:

> Because print takes a LIST, anything in the LIST is evaluated in list
>   context

And in list context, the list assignment result is **the left side** of assignment - which is, as you probably guessed, an empty list in this case. Printed, it just gives you an empty string.

I hope this example will be helpful to show the difference the context makes here.

```
my ($a, $b);
my $x = ($a, $b) = (1,2,3,4);
say $x;                        # 4  
my @x = ($a, $b) = (1,2,3,4);  
say join '-', @x;              # 1-2
```

Comment: well im not asking the first line. im asking the second line why it prints nothing

Comment: @texasbruce: Until you understand its basic concepts (e.g. context), it might seem so.

Comment: I never see a language that returns right hand side of an assignment.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
$count = () = $string =~ /\d+/g;
```

that `()` will put `$string =~ /\d+/g` in list context, so it will return a list of matched numbers, therefore the above statement equals something like

```
$count = (() = (num1, num2, ...))
```

the second assignment is a list assignment, and that `$count =` will put it in scalar context, and a list assignment in scalar context will return how many element there are in the right side of `=`.

The parameters of `print` is a list, and every of its elements will be evaluated in list context. Therefore in

```
print (() = $string =~ /\d+/g);
```

it equals you assigned `$string =~ /\d+/g` to `()` first, and use that result list (it is a empty list) as the arguments of `print`, which means that `print` statement equals

```
print ();
```

This could be fixed easily:

```
print scalar(() = $str =~ m/\d+/g), "\n";
```

`scalar` will put its argument to scalar context.

Another example, in

```
(() = @list, "\n")
```

the first element of this list, which is `() = @list`, will be evaluated in list context, and will result an empty list. So the above list equals

```
((), "\n")
```

Because sublists will be automatically interpolated in list, so the final result of the above list is simply

```
("\n")
```

Comment: But why `print (() = $string =~ /\d+/g);` does not print anything?

Comment: @texasbruce That `print` will try to output the empty list.

Comment: so u mean `(()=(list))` returns empty list in list context but return number of list elements in scalar context? why the scalar context does not return 0 as empty list?

Comment: @texasbruce In `(()=@list)`, the outer `()` means this is a list constructor, which will put every element of it in a list context. So the first element, which is list assignment `() = @list`, is evaluated in list context, not in scalar context, and will return an empty list.

Comment: Nipick: There is no such thing as a “list constructor”. In Perl, lists are not data structures (unlike arrays), they just describe a transient bunch of values on the stack. They have a role in Perl's semantics, but aren't actual “things” you can use. Nitpicking my nitpick: The perl VM actually has a “list” opcode which performs bookkeeping to prevent stack corruption. However, this opcode has no corresponding syntax, and parens *only* ever sort out precedence.

Comment: @amon Nice nitpicking. Yes, list is not Perl data structure, and there is no such thing as 'list constructor'. In Perl, a list is just  a list of things (values, expressions, variables).